# Arithmetic with shiny input

Tags: r, shiny

I have simulated annealing function which finds the global minimum. I am taking inputs from a shiny dashboard and I have radiobuttons to choose between minimise and maximise. I want to be able to find the global maximum by simply multiplying my input equation by -1. How can I do this arithmetic in shiny. Here is what I have so far but not sure what to put in the else if statement.
This is from the UI:

```
textInput("ObjectiveFun",
                           h3("Objective Function"),
                           value = "(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2"),
                 radioButtons("maxormin",
                              h3("Goal"),
                              choices=c("Minimise"="min", "Maximise"="max")),
```

This is from the server:

```
 observeEvent(input$maxormin,{
      if(input$maxormin == min)
        {
        Func <- input$ObjectiveFn
        }
      else if(input$maxormin == max)
        {
        #trying to get: Func <- input$-1*(ObjectiveFn)
        }
    })
```

Here is the entire shiny app so far:

```
library(shiny)
source("simulated_annealing.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simulated Annealing App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel("User input",
                 textInput("ObjectiveFun",
                           h3("Objective Function"),
                           value = "(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2"),
                 radioButtons("maxormin",
                              h3("Goal"),
                              choices=c("Minimise"="min", "Maximise"="max")),
                 numericInput("XL",
                              h3("Lower bound of x"),
                              value = -5),
                 numericInput("XU",
                              h3("Upper bound of x"),
                              value = 5),
                 numericInput("YL",
                              h3("Lower bound of y"),
                              value = -5),
                 numericInput("YU",
                              h3("Upper bound of y"),
                              value = 5),
                 numericInput("TEMP",
                              h3("Starting temperature"),
                              value = 100),
                 numericInput("NEPOCHS",
                              h3("Number of epochs"),
                              value = 25),
                 numericInput("NITER",
                              h3("Maximum number of iterations per epoch"),
                              value = 8),
                 numericInput("AMIN",
                              h3("Minimum number of moves per epoch"),
                              value = 3),
                 sliderInput(
                   "ALPHA",
                   h3("Cooling rate"),
                   min=0,
                   max=1,
                   value=0.95,
                   step = NULL,
                   round = FALSE,
                   ticks = TRUE,
                   animate = FALSE,
                   width = NULL,
                   sep = ",",
                   pre = NULL,
                   post = NULL,
                   timeFormat = NULL,
                   timezone = NULL,
                   dragRange = TRUE
                 ),
                 actionButton("Go","Simulate"),
    ),
  mainPanel("System Outputs",
            textOutput("value")
            )
),
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  Sim <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    xlower <- input$XL
    xupper <- input$XU
    ylower <- input$YL
    yupper <- input$YU
    temp <- input$TEMP
    alpha <- input$ALPHA
    nepochs <- input$NEPOCHS
    I <- input$NITER
    A <- input$AMIN
    observeEvent(input$maxormin,{
      if(input$maxormin == min)
        {
        Func <- input$ObjectiveFn
        }
      else if(input$maxormin == max)
        {
        
        }
    })
    value <- simannealing(Func,goal,temp,I,A,alpha,nepochs,xlower,xupper,ylower,yupper)
    paste("Final value is:", value[3],"at x value: ", value[1], "and y value: ", value[2])
  })
  output$FinalValues <- renderText({
  Sim()
  })
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I have added my entire shiny code. Should I add the simulated annealing function aswell?

Comment: @shongololo you should not add the entire shiny code, but provide an app with the minimum code required to show your problem.